# Pairing attack on the discrete logarithm problem

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $p > 3$ be a prime, let $E/\mathbb{F}_p$ be a supersingular curve, let $N > \sqrt{p}$ be a prime dividing $p + 1$, and let $\mu_N$ denote the multiplicative group of $N$th roots of unity in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

> (a) Prove that $\mu_N \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$
>
> (b) Prove that $\#E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2}) = (p + 1)^2$ and $E[N] \subseteq E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$

Comment: This is rather difficult to read. Could you please try MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ?

Comment: it's not easier for you to write with $\LaTeX$?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta_N) = \mathbb{F}_{p^f}$ where $f = \text{ord}(p \bmod N)$. That  $N^2 \ |\ \#E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$ and $N$ is prime implies $E[N] \subset E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$

Comment: I edited the question a bit based on some educated guessing. Please check. What tools/results have you learned about?